# Request header not set in test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I have a test which is trying to login and get details. I need to pass a bearer token in request header for this operation. Please see the below code. I could see that the header seldom has the headers that I set. Can anyone give me a pointer to fix this issue?

I am using Laravel 7.2.2, PHP 7.4,

And I am running php artisan test

Code:

```
public function a_user_can_get_details()
    {
        $this->create_user();

        $response = $this->json('POST', 
                    '/api/login', 
                    [
                        "email" => "john.doe@example.com",
                        "password" => "john123"
                    ]);
        $response->assertSuccessful();

        $token = Str::replaceLast('"', '', Str::replaceFirst('"', '', $response->getContent()));
        $headers = [
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
                    ];


        $response = $this->withHeaders($headers)
                        ->get('api/user');

        $response->assertSuccessful();
        $this->assertCount(1, User::all());

    }
```

And here is the error I am getting. Actually, the test must pass. That is the right user name and password:

```
Response status code [403] is not a successful status code. Failed asserting that false is true.

  at tests/Feature/UserTest.php:141
    137|
    138|         $response = $this->withHeaders($headers)
    139|                         ->get('api/user');
    140|
  > 141|         $response->assertSuccessful();
    142|         $this->assertCount(1, User::all());
    143|
    144|     }
    145|
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are logging in user on `create_user` function?

Comment: I am not logging in inside create_user.
`private function create_user(){
        return $this->post('/api/user', [
            "name" => "John Doe",
            "email" => "john.doe@example.com",
            "password" => "john123",
            "password_confirmation" => "john123"
        ]);
    }`

Comment: Do you have any middleware? Since you are getting 403 i assume it is a permission error which is getting provided by a middleware.

Comment: I am using sanctum for authentication. No other middlewares in action other than the default middlewares + sanctum + spatie permissions. In addition, I found there was an issue with the string manipulation. I changed that. Now I am getting 401. below is the dd excerpts which has the header:

`
      #headers: array:3 [
        "cache-control" => array:1 [
          0 => "no-cache, private"
        ]
        "date" => array:1 [
          0 => "Sat, 28 Mar 2020 03:05:31 GMT"
        ]
        "content-type" => array:1 [
          0 => "application/json"
        ]
`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

Cause: I had added a middleware condition in Spatie Permissions to check for a permission for that specific route. I had to remove that to get this working.

Instead of that, I now, check the logged in status of the user. So that the route could be hit and needed checks are done inside the route.

Thanks all for the questions/comments which helped me to solve this.